# Configure swagger with Nestjs + Azure functions

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am trying to develop my nestjs using azure functions following this article:
https://trilon.io/blog/deploy-nestjs-azure-functions

I have configured Swagger in my application as follows:

```js
...
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('App title')
    .setDescription('App description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth(
      {
        type: 'http',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      },
      'authorization',
    )
    .addTag('freight')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);
...
```

When I run the app in development, I can access my swagger UI by navigating to `/swagger`, however when I run `npm run build && func host start`, I receive `500` error, which also happens when I hit a non-existing route.

All other routes that are registered in the application work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nestjs has a module you need to load for this. [nestjs-openapi](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction)

Next you will need to specify a few configuration items.

Note: Main.ts is not used at all.

Sync ports with:

```
func host start --port 3000
```

!! Use the app instance within the main.azure.ts. Example assumes global prefix defined above the code below.

```
...
//config
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle('My Title')
.setDescription('My Description')
.setVersion('1.0')
.setBasePath('api-docs')
.build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

SwaggerModule.setup('api-docs', app, document, {
  useGlobalPrefix: true,
});

// order matters here. 
app.init() 
// port that is used for swagger ui. Sync with Az Fx. 
app.listen(3000)
```

Now you can route to localhost:3000/{global_prefix}/api-docs to load swagger ui.

Comment: Looks to be that either nest or swagger ui has a bug that requires the app.listen and azure function to run on same port. As well the setBasePath must be set to match the route in the .setup portion. Consider this a work around.

Comment: We did same steps but still not loading swagger for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the code below

Step 01: config package.json

`"start:azure": "npm run build && func host start --port 3000"`

Step 02: config at main.azure.ts

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export async function createApp(): Promise<INestApplication> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

  // setup swagger
  const swaggerOptions = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('NestJS Azure Functions')
    .setDescription('NestJS Azure Functions')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('nestjs')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerOptions);
  SwaggerModule.setup('/docs', app, document, {
    useGlobalPrefix: true,
  });

  await app.init();
  await app.listen(3000);

  return app;
}
```

Step 03: Now u can run `npm run start:azure` and u can route localhost:3000/api/docs

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**