# Swagger for Nestjs with Azure functions - Not working

Tags: azure, function, swagger, nestjs

We are developing azure functions with nestjs using @nestjs/azure-func-http

https://trilon.io/blog/deploy-nestjs-azure-functions

The swagger is not loading for the function app. It works only at nest app level.

func host start -build --port 3001 does not load swagger at http://localhost:3001/swagger.

The code is written at main.azure.ts.

```
export async function createApp(): Promise\<INestApplication\> {

    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const options = new DocumentBuilder().build();
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
    SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);
    app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
    await app.init();
    await app.listen(3001); // default azure func port
    return app;

}
export { AppModule };
```

After deploying to azure, it needs to work.

What is missing. Need solution. Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Refer [Document](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction) (or) follow below steps to work with Swagger for NestJS Azure functions:**

- I have created a default NestJs Azure functions with below commands:

```
1. npm new <project_name>
2. cd <project_name>
3. npm add @azure/functions
4. npm add @schematics/angular
5. nest add @nestjs/azure-func-http
```

- **To work with Swagger, need to load Nestjs OpenAI:**
- Install Swagger Module:

> npm install --save @nestjs/swagger

[image]

- Import **Swagger module** in  `src/main.ts` function code:

```
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from  '@nestjs/swagger';
```

**My function code:**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Swagger example')
    .setDescription('The Open API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('Swagger')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

- **Open Terminal =>Run `npm run start`:**

[image]

- **Hit `https://localhost:3000/api` in browser:**

[image]

**References:**

***Also you can refer [Configure swagger with Nestjs + Azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71652129/19991670) by @Kentonbmax***

Comment: Will this work with azureFunction? For me , I can see swagger with npm start, but when ran as azure function, its not loading

Comment: Yes, it works with Azure Function. I have provided the same in the answer.

Comment: Ohk! for me tried all steps but still swagger not coming on specified path